# Arrow function vs regular function while handling events in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, event-handling, arrow-functions

Kindly correct me if I'm wrong.

```
() => this.handleClick()
```

is same as

```
function callHandleClick(){

return this.handleClick()

}
```

But the below works.

```
<input type="submit" onClick={ () => this.handleClick() }/>
```

But, this doesn't

```
<input type="submit" onClick={function callHandleClick(){return this.handleClick()}}/>
```

I have defined the handleClick method.
Is it possible to use a normal function instead of arrow function to handle the click event?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are 'Arrow Functions' and 'Functions' equivalent / interchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-interchangeable)

Answer (score 1):

```
() => this.handleClick()
```

is not the same as

```
function callHandleClick(){
  return this.handleClick()
}
```

The equivalent for that would be:

```
const callHandleClick = () => this.handleClick()
```

Therefore, you are defining a function inside the `handleClick`. Instead define it outside and pass it like:

```
onClick={callHandleClick}
```